# Write the Linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In 1940 there were $245,300$ immigrants admitted to a country. In 2006 there were $1,060,431$.
Write a linear equation expressing the number of immigrants, $y$, in terms of $t$, the number of years after 1900.
What is the estimate of immigrants in 2015?

Comment: It helps to rewrite the data as $(t,y)$ so that it is easier to work. So the first data point is $(40,245300)$. Can you do the other and find the line's equation?

Comment: I think other will be (106,1060431). Am I right?

Comment: Correct. Now find the slope/gradient of the line and make an equation.

Comment: slope comes out to be 12350.46

Comment: how to find value of c?

Comment: You can substitute one of your data points into the equation and solve for $c$.

Comment: equation is y=12350x+c. Please tell me the value of c?

Comment: Slight duplicate. This also involves an extrapolation piece.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have an equation $y=12350.46t+c$, you can substitute either $(40,245300)$ or $(106,1060431)$ in for $(t,y)$ and solve for $c$.

$245300 = (12350.46)(40)+c \\
245300 = 494019 + c \\
c = -248719$

It isn't clear from the question how much accuracy is needed in the answer so I let the calculator keep track of all the decimals and rounded the final answer to the nearest person.

For the last part, use $t=2015-1900 = 115$ in the equation and get the estimate.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked a thousand times with different data points already, but here's the general approach for a line traversing $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ given that $x_1\neq x_2$:

$$f(x) = y_1 + \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1) = \underbrace{\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}}_{=:m} x + \underbrace{y_1 - \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}x_1}_{=:c}$$